# Find out if document exists?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsfilemanager

I am trying to find out if a document exists by running

```
    NSString *DocumentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *theFile = [[DocumentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileName] retain];
    NSLog(@"File : %@",theFile);
    NSLog(@"FileName : %@", FileName);
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:theFile];
    NSLog(@"FileExists : %@", fileExists);
```

I know that the document is there, but I want to run this to find out and if say its been deleted are something then do something else. But all I get as my NSLog is

```
 FileExists : (null)
```

I have looked at some tutorials and they say this is right. I'm I missing something?

Comment: How have you verified that the file exists? Can you open it with Terminal based on the `theFile`?

Comment: Yes. But it just doesn't seem to be able to see it.

Comment: You need to re-examine everything. Your code is good (except the %@ of the BOOL in the last NSLog(), the naming convention of the variable "FileName"-should start with a lower case letter and the unneeded retain, really consider using ARC). We can't see your file and directory structure so we can't help on that but that is the single most probably issue. NSFileManager works. The problem is in your code. Some assumption you have made is incorrect or some test you have made is mis-leading you.

Comment: where do you store your file?

Comment: This is still happening, I know it exists because it is actually loading the file. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code work for me. saving file in `Resources->file.txt`

```
 NSString *myFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/file.txt"];
 NSLog(@"FileExist %d",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myFilePath]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this line instead of your's:

```
NSLog(@"FileExists : %d", fileExists);
```

%@ format specifier is used for objects only, and prints in result of description method call for specified object

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't really make a difference it just prints 0 instead of null.

Comment: A zero means it doesn't exist.  How do you know the document is there?  Check path.